# in-app billing error : unable to buy item,error response 5 developer error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have an in-app billing service set up where there are two consumables and one non-consumable.

For the non-consumable, I am checking the purchase list and if the item is already owned, I want the user to refrain from purchasing again and instead make the benefit available. I have two classes: Guess.java (Launcher file) and Purchase.java (In-app billing setup file)

**Inside Guess.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Guess.this,Purchase.class);
intent.putExtra("buy_2x", "buy_2x");
startActivity(intent);
```

The buy_2x is the non-consumable (buying-choice is 2 in the code below while the consumables are call buying choices 0 and 1) that I am referring to. Inside the Purchase.java the code is as follows

```
public class Purchase extends Activity {

    IInAppBillingService mService;
    private Bundle extras;
    private int add=0;//add coins to the kitty


    private int buying_choice;

    private String ITEM_SKU_SELECTION;


    private static final String TAG = "com.apps.guess.inappbilling";
    IabHelper mHelper;

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "<64-char> long";

        Intent intent = getIntent();
            String buy2x_recd =intent.getExtras().getString("buy_2x"); 

        //this is a class that contains static variables and I am using choices
            //0,1,2...choice 2 is for the non-consumable buy_2x
        if(UserData.getBuying_choice()!=2) ITEM_SKU_SELECTION = selectbuyingChoice(UserData.getBuying_choice());

            //callService() method referred below 
        if(buy2x_recd.equalsIgnoreCase("buy_2x"))callService();

        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
        mHelper.startSetup(new 
                IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                      public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) 
                  {
                        if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In-app Billing setup failed: = ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing setup failed: ");
                      } else {             
                            Log.d(TAG, "In-app Billing is set up OK");
                            mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(Purchase.this, ITEM_SKU_SELECTION, 10001,mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
                            mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true, TAG);
                  }
                   }
                });



    }//onCreate() ends

    public void callService(){
        mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() 
        {
        @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name,
                    IBinder service) {
                  mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                    Log.d("TEST", "mService ready to go!");
                    checkownedItems();  
        }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                 mService = null;
            }
        };

        bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"), mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }

     private void checkownedItems()
        {

    try {
        Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);

        int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {
           ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
              ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
           ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
              ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
           ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
              ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");
           String continuationToken = 
              ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

           for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
              String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
              String signature = signatureList.get(i);
              String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

              if(sku.equalsIgnoreCase("buy_2x"))
              {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Purchase.this);
                builder.setTitle("Purchased Already");
                builder.setMessage("You have already purchased the 2X option. Do you want to enable it?");

                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have decided to double your gains!.Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        int double_2x_value=2*getResources().getIntArray(R.array.start_parameters)[2];
                        UserData.writeData(""+double_2x_value, Purchase.this, UserData.get2XFile());
                        UserData.setWinningValue(""+double_2x_value);

                        UserData.writeData("true", Purchase.this, UserData.getDoubleXPurchaseFile());
                        UserData.setBuy2X(true);

                        UserData.setBuying_choice(0);
                        dialog1.dismiss();

                         Intent intent = new Intent(Purchase.this, com.glambleapps.guesstheword.Guess.class);
                         startActivity(intent);

                        }});

                builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog1, int which) {
                        dialog1.dismiss();
                        }});
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                  break;
              }


              // do something with this purchase information
              // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
           } 

           // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again 
           // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(Purchase.this, "No 2X purchase available on your device",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ITEM_SKU_SELECTION=selectbuyingChoice(2);
        } 


    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    private String selectbuyingChoice(int buying_choice2) {
        String ITEM_SKU_SELECTION=null;
        switch(buying_choice2){
        case 0:
            ITEM_SKU_SELECTION = "buy_200_coins";
            add = 200;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have decided to purchase 200 Coins.Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case 1:
            ITEM_SKU_SELECTION = "buy_1200_coins";
            add = 1200;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have decided to purchase 1200 Coins.Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        case 2:
            ITEM_SKU_SELECTION = "buy_2x";
            add = 0;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have decided to double your winnings!.Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;

        default:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO BUYING CHOICE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        }

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ITEM_SKU_SELECTION = "+ITEM_SKU_SELECTION, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return ITEM_SKU_SELECTION;

    }

    IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
              new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
               public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, 
                     IabResult result) {

             if (result.isSuccess()) {               


                 int total =add+Integer.parseInt(UserData.getCoins_remaining());

                 if(!(ITEM_SKU_SELECTION.equalsIgnoreCase("buy_2x")))
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successful purchase done of "+add+" Guess-Coins!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                 if(ITEM_SKU_SELECTION.equalsIgnoreCase("buy_2x")){

                     int double_2x_value=2*getResources().getIntArray(R.array.start_parameters)[2];
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "2X - Double your winnings! purchase is successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     UserData.setWinningValue(""+double_2x_value);


                 }

                 add=0;
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Purchase.this, Guess.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

             } else {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO PURCHASE DONE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Purchase.this, Guess.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

             }
          }
        };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;

        if(mServiceConn != null)
        {
            unbindService(mServiceConn);
            mServiceConn=null;
        }

    }

    public void consumeItem() {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
    }


    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener 
       = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
           public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
              Inventory inventory) {


              if (result.isFailure()) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(Purchase.this, Guess.class);
                  startActivity(intent);

              } else {
                     mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU_SELECTION), mConsumeFinishedListener);
              }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
          if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {     
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          }

          if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
              Toast.makeText(PurchaseActivity.this,"Sorry, you have canceled your coins purchase.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }


    }

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
    = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                    Purchase purchase) 
    {
       if (result.isFailure()) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(Purchase.this, Guess.class);
             startActivity(intent);

          return;
     }      
     else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU_SELECTION)) {consumeItem();
    }

   }
};





}//class ends
```

I am getting the following warning :

```
Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND } android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:517  Purchase.callService:107  Purchase.onCreate:68
```

The error is as follows:

```
IabHelper(25782): In-app billing error: Unable to buy item, Error response: 5:Developer Error
```

The UserData.java stores some values and writes datain text files. They have no issues.

What is this issue? Please help. Thank you

Comment: Have you found solution for this ? Even I am facing same issue.

Comment: Hi, experiencing the same problem, people say it's down to the apk not signed correctly however I've uploaded a release to Google Play Alpha and I'm testing the release that is there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to buy the item logged on your device with your GooglePlay developer account?

Google doesn't allow it. You should use a different one.

In developer console, go to Account Settings and add some accounts to test. Then, logged with one of them, try to purchase the item. You should be able to achieve it.

Edit:

Checking the documentation, also I've found that you must to test it with a valid signed apk http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html

Answer (score 0):

you just need give the PAY_THROUGH_...(evrey store that you inapp that) On Manifest:
for example for cafebazar store :

or for play store : ....

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. I can't make heads or tails of it. Also please use the provided formatting to separate code from normal text